# How to distribute SQL Server Express with my software

Tags: sql-server, express, deployment

I've developed a software that uses SQL Server Express.

From the legal point of view, I would like to be confirmed that what I have developed is legal, as the user can click on a SQL Server Express button within my software, a click that starts the installation process.

I really would like an official yes/no answer if possible from Microsoft.

Thank you in advance,

Bracha Goldstein

Comment: Yes, you are free to use SQL Server Express any way you like....

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be wise to contact Microsoft directly, especially when it comes to a legal/licensing point of view. Proof from the vendor is crucial.

Call them, ask for a licensing expert and explain your situation.
Your local contact details can be found at https://www.microsoft.com/